# How can I test a class that uses the Storage Facade?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, orchestra

In a Laravel 5 package I am making there is a class `FileSelector` that uses the *Storage-facade* in a certain method.

```
public function filterFilesOnDate($files, DateTime $date)
{
    return array_filter($files, function($file) use($date){
        return Storage::lastModified($file) < $date->getTimeStamp();
    });
}
```

This class takes a path (to some files) and a `Storage::disk()`in it's constructor.

Now I am trying to write some basic unit tests for this specific class using the Orchestra Testbench.

The setUp-function looks like this:

```
protected $fileSelector;
protected $date;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->date = new DateTime();
    $this->fileSelector = new fileSelector('tests/_data/backups', Storage::disk('local'));
}
```

The failing test is:

```
public function test_if_files_are_filtered_on_date()
{
    $files = Storage::allFiles('tests/_data/backups');

    $filteredFiles = $this->fileSelector->filterFilesOnDate($files, $this->date);
}
```

`Storage::allFiles('tests/_data/backups')` returns **no files** at all.
The path is correct because using the *File-facade* returns the needed files but this isn't compatible with the `filterFilesOnDate()`-method because it uses Storage.

Using the *File-facade* generates the following error:

```
League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at tests/_data/backups/ElvisPresley.zip
```

Am I using the Storage-methods wrong in the test or have I stumbled on a limitation of Orchestra/Testbench?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, turns out I didn't completely understand how `Storage`and disks worked.

Using things like `Storage::lastModified()` calls the default Filesystem specified in the filesystem-config.

Since this is a test there is no config.

What `Storage::disk()` does, is create an instance of `FilesystemAdapter` using a Filesystem-object  So a Storage object needs to be 'recreated'.

So:

```
$this->fileSelector = new FileSelector('tests/_data/backups', Storage::disk('local'));
```

Becomes:

```
$this->disk = new Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter(
    new Filesystem(new Local($this->root))
);

$this->fileSelector = new FileSelector($this->disk, $this->path);
```

(`$this->path`is the path the where the files I use for testing are stored)

It was also pointed out to me that I should set the lastModified-timestamps manually everytime the test is run to avoid differing test results.

```
foreach (scandir($this->testFilesPath) as $file)
{
    touch($this->testFilesPath . '/' . $file, time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 5));
}
```

Using `touch` you can create files or set timestamps of files. In this case, they are set to 5 days.